Help identifying an episode where the grandmother is radioactive?
I watched a portion of a TV show years ago that involved an old woman who glowed in the dark. From what I remember a man was shown in to the grandmother's bedroom by her family members, then the grandmother says something like "Look what they've done to me" and when the lights are turned off she glows in the dark.
I believe she was accusing her family members of having done something to her to make her radioactive and I don't really remember why they did this to her. I wasn't sure why they showed the grandmother to the man and why they didn't try to conceal her? 
I believe the show was in black and white. I thought it might be an episode of twilight zone, but I can't find it based on the description.
Does anyone know what show this is from?

I'm not sure you're looking for a TV show. This sounds very much like the B&W screwball comedy Murder, He Says from 1945 with Fred MacMurray. From Wiki: 

a slapstick comedy film about a murderous rural family and the hapless pollster who becomes entangled in their hunt for a cache of money. [...]  Grandma Fleagle has hidden $70,000 stolen by Bonnie and her now-executed father, but refuses to divulge where to her unwanted relations for a very good reason: she tells Pete that she has been poisoned by them. Before she dies, she teaches Pete a nonsensical song.

The poison in question is Radium. There's a scene where the family members show the pollster into Grandma's room, she instructs him to turn off the light and he sees that she glows in the dark.

Grandma: I glow, don't I? ... I'm poisoned! And they're the ones that done it to me.

You can see the relevant clip on TCM's website here.

sounds very close.

This is the clip I was thinking of. I never would have guessed it was a comedy.
